# System.Web.Optimization not found when building MVC 4 app with TeamCity

Tags: visual-studio-2010, asp.net-mvc-4

I am developing in VS2010, MVC4 using the System.Web.Optimization nuget package. My project builds without error locally but when I try to build it on a Team City agent, which is a Window XP machine, I get a build error stating that System.Web.Optimization cannot be found.

I have installed MVC4 on the agent machine. How should I go about correctly deploying this package in MVC4?

Comment: Can you post the output from the attempted build in TeamCity?  I know TeamCity has the ability to download and install NuGet packages in the build process, it sounds like it isn't doing that in your setup, or failing the process.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you need is for NuGet to get the missing packages at build time.

http://docs.nuget.org/docs/workflows/using-nuget-without-committing-packages

Comment: Packages references in the project files were not mapping correctly when I deployed.

Answer (score 0):

I stumbled across this when searching the same problem. As of version 2.7 NuGet will automatically restore packages on build. For my solution, here is what I did:

1) In Source Control Explorer delete the \packages folder. Check in the change.

2) Queue up a new (TFS) build.

3) When it begins, it will take longer than usual because it will download the packages for the projects.

The references will now be resolved on the build server, and the solution will build just fine.